# Power BI multiply row by row based on another table value (calculated)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI.

I have a table (Purchases) that has two values that must be multiplied or divided, price and currency rate; based on people's choice. The calculations must be done row by row.

On excel, i have an options button for the choice and in my table Purchases i have column with a formula based on options cell value.

```
IF(cell options=1, price \* currency rate, price / currency rate)
```

Now, in Power BI, i created another table (Currency Choice), with the rows: mxn (value = 1) and usd (value = 2). I added an slicer so people can choose the price currency and this selections creates a Measure.

I am trying to have my table Purchases multiply or divide each row based on the Currency Choice selection (Measure), it doesn't work.

Any advice.

Thanks.

Someone told me to add a custom column to my Purchases table in the Query Editor, but i cannot add a Measure.

Example Table Purchases:

```
Price   Rate    Currency
100      15       mxn
200      15       usd
100      15       mxn
500      15       mxn
400      15       usd
```

Example Table Currency Choice:

```
Currency   Value
  mxn        1
  usd        2
```

If people pick usd, the Measure would be 2 so, i expect the rows to be like this:

```
Price   Rate    Currency   New Price
100      15       mxn       6.66  (100/15)
200      15       usd       200
100      15       mxn       6.66  (100/15)
500      15       mxn       33.33
400      15       usd       400
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd need an iterating function to retrieve the correct rate for each record.

```
IF(
    Test=True(),
    SUMX('Table', [Amount] * RELATED([Rate]) ),
    SUMX('Table', DIVIDE([Amount] , RELATED([Rate]))
)
```